# Uninstalling packages installed by debuginfo-install

Tags: centos, yum, debugging

How do I delete debug packages that are installed by `debuginfo-install`?

When I search for them via `sudo yum list installed` none of the installed packages are listed, even when I enabled the debuginfo repository.

A lot of packages have been installed when reporting bugs via `ABRT` but I would like to clean them up after I have reported the bug.

Comment: what does `yum remove "*-debuginfo"` say?

Comment: `No Match for argument: *-debuginfo.`
I also ran: `sudo yum --enablerepo *debuginfo remove "*-debuginfo"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AIUI the latest versions of abrt don't actually install anything, they just use yum to download the packages and it unpacks the data itself.

Update: https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/ABRT#head-6ec8c2ca60fa7a4f2e8167a19299ea6d61217df2 suggests that abrt-action-analyze-ccpp-local unpacks them to /var/cache/abrt-di/.

Unless you have the very latest yum there is no way that "yum list installed" doesn't show you all the packages, and even with the very latest you need the query_install_excludes=true and then it only excludes those things specified on the cmd line.

Comment: Thanks for the response; do you know where it unpacks that data to?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching how to remove debuginfo packages as well and here's the method I used eventually:

```
yum list installed | grep debuginfo | cut -f1 -d" " | xargs yum -y remove
```

Maybe it could be useful to someone else.